# Error while adding custom SSIS data source to visual studio toolbox

Tags: visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, toolbox

I've created a custom data source using the instructions given in the following link:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136088.aspx

However once i build the project and try to add the new datasource to the toolbox, i get the following error:

> There are no components in
>   'C:\Somepath\bin\Debug\CustomDataSource.dll' that can be placed on the
>   toolbox

following are the tools i've used:

To create and build the custom datasource;
Visual Studio 2010 & build in Framework 3.5

To create the SSIS package
SSIS - SQL Server 2008 R2 & SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio (VS2008)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Nandun

Comment: After you build the .dll, what step(s) do you perform? Could you edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i found the answer to my problem; here's the solution and hope it helps someone.

ref - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403356.aspx

1. copy the dll to the following folder(s). the exact folder depends on whether your on x64 or x86 (doesn't hurt to have it on both):

   C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\PipelineComponents
   C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\PipelineComponents
2. Install the dll to your GAC. you will need to have it signed to do this.
3. In BI Dev Studio, go to Tools > Choose Toolbox Items. you will find your data source in the "SSIS Dataflow Items" tab

For steps 1 & 2 you might find it helpful to have a post build event like follows:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe" -u $(TargetName) 
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe" -iF $(TargetFileName) 
copy $(TargetPath) "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\PipelineComponents" 
copy $(TargetPath) "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\PipelineComponents"
```

Small Edit to the answer:

If you're using SSIS 2012 with BIDS 2010, the toolbox items get added automatically (i.e. u don't have to go to Tools > Choose Toolbox Items) you just need to copy it to the dll right places (ref - http://fendy-huang.blogspot.com/2011/09/how-to-add-ssis-custom-component-to.html):

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\PipelineComponents   
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\PipelineComponents   
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Tasks   
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Tasks
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a [report here](http://forums.asp.net/t/949306.aspx/1) that a similar problem was resolved by making the class public.  (Also, signing the assembly and placing it in the GAC.)

[Here is a case](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?571200-RESOLVED-Adding-a-class-to-the-ToolBox) where someone needed to to implement IComponent and inherit from Component class.

I see number of other posts when I google the error message.  Did any of these help?

Comment: Unfortunately i haven't been able to find any solutions yet. my component is of type PipelineComponent. and does not implement IComponent. most of these articles speak of adding UI controls to the toolbox. bbut my issue is with a SSIS data source. thanks for your response.